Calling a C Function Using Fortran
For a while now, I've been trying to take over MATLAB Simulations (Generating C Code from Simulink models), and take that over to PSCAD. So, the way it needs to be done in PSCAD is that you have a Fortran wrapper function that will call your C function.
The Fortran script will define a bunch of variables that will act as either input or output. These will then be passed onto the C code, which will then perform my required necessary computations, send the output back, and ready to be observed in PSCAD.
The problem I'm having? I've been tinkering with Visual Studio to compile all of these C programs into a .lib, and even a .dll. But, when I build the program, PSCAD's compiler gives the following error:
undefined reference to rt_onestep_
rt_onestep is a function that I wrote in my C Code, and Fortran should be calling it, but it just can't find it.
Is this some kind of compiler incompatibility problem? What should I do?
This is the function that Fortran is trying to call
/*
 * Academic License - for use in teaching, academic research, and meeting
 * course requirements at degree granting institutions only.  Not for
 * government, commercial, or other organizational use.
 *
 * File: ert_main.c
 *
 * Code generated for Simulink model 'CInterface0'.
 *
 * Model version                  : 12.6
 * Simulink Coder version         : 23.2 (R2023b) 01-Aug-2023
 * C/C++ source code generated on : Mon Jun  3 13:10:19 2024
 *
 * Target selection: ert_shrlib.tlc
 * Embedded hardware selection: Intel->x86-64 (Windows64)
 * Code generation objectives: Unspecified
 * Validation result: Not run
 */

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>            /* This example main program uses printf/fflush */
#include "CInterface0.h" 
#include "rtwtypes.h"              /* Model header file */

void (rt_onestep)(double* freq, double* mod, double* Ia, double* Ib, double* Ic);
void (rt_onestep)(double* freq, double* mod, double* Ia, double* Ib, double* Ic)
{
  CInterface0_U.freq=*freq;
  CInterface0_U.mod=*mod;
  CInterface0_step();
  *Ia=CInterface0_Y.Iabc[0];
  *Ib=CInterface0_Y.Iabc[1];
  *Ic=CInterface0_Y.Iabc[2];
}




This is the Fortran code in PSCAD.
      
      ! ------------------------------------------------------------
      ! Subroutine "Untitled_Fortran_CI"
      ! 
      SUBROUTINE Untitled_Fortran_CI(freq, mod, Ia, Ib, Ic)
      
      REAL freq, mod, Ia, Ib, Ic
            
            ! ----------------------------------------
            ! Intel Interface
            ! ----------------------------------------
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
                  
                  ! --------------------
                  ! Fortran Interface to C Function
                  ! --------------------
                  INTERFACE
                        SUBROUTINE RT_ONESTEP(freq, mod, Ia, Ib, Ic)
                              !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C :: RT_ONESTEP
                              !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: freq
                              !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: mod
                              !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: Ia
                              !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: Ib
                              !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: Ic
                              REAL freq, mod, Ia, Ib, Ic
                        END SUBROUTINE
                  END INTERFACE
#endif
            
            ! Call C Function
            CALL RT_ONESTEP(freq, mod, Ia, Ib, Ic)
            
      END
      
      



Thanks a lot in advance.

You've tagged as using [tag:gfortran] but your code seems to assume __INTEL_COMPILER is defined. If you are using gfortran and that preprocessor variable isn't defined, how are you giving gfortran the interface for the C function? More specifically, why aren't you using bind(c)?

Firstly, the interface block is inside the #ifdef that will be ignored by gfortran. Secondly, the !DEC$ directives would also be ignored by gfortran, they are only for the DEC compiler and the descendants (Compaq, Intel). As already suggested, just use the standard bind(C) instead. Although theoretically there are also some !GCC$ directives available, I strongly recommend not use them here.
